# usb data reverted upon removal in Linux

Tags: linux, file-io, filesystems

I am trying to change a file in the vfat partition on a card with `raspbian` on it.

The boot partition is `vfat`.

After mounting it I tried changing a file on it with `vim`, `nano` and `gedit` (in the GUI), even overwritten it with `cp`, but if I remove and reinsert the card reader in the computer, the changes are reverted.

I also tried using the `sync` command after editing with no avail. And I was using root in all cases.

Could anybody please tell me how to permanently edit the files on the card?

Comment: Is the mounted file system read-only ?

Comment: Don't know. Maybe. No program told me that the fs is read only and before I removed the adaptor, the card would reflect those changes as if they were permanent. (A subsequent cat of the file would show the modified version up until the card is removed)